# Grep is not retrieving string with space

Tags: grep, whitespace

I have a series of headings in a file that have names like this:

```
grep ">scaffold_3" DM_v6.1_unanchoredScaffolds.fasta 
>scaffold_3
>scaffold_303
>scaffold_31
>scaffold_34
>scaffold_36
>scaffold_37
>scaffold_39
>scaffold_33
>scaffold_300
```

I would like to select only the first, so I tried:

```
$ grep ">scaffold_3 " file.fasta 
$
$ grep ">scaffold_3[[:blank:]]" file.fasta 
$
$ grep ">scaffold_3\t" file.fasta 
$
$ grep ">scaffold_3\ " file.fasta 
$
$ grep ">scaffold_3 " file.fasta 
$
$ grep ">scaffold_3[[:space:]]" file.fasta 
$
$ grep ">scaffold_3$" file.fasta 
>scaffold_3
```

How can I get the exact name but not the synonyms, given that the character after the name might be a space, tab, newline (perhaps from Windows too) and that `[[:space:]]` did not work?

Thank you

Comment: Your last attempt worked fine? `grep ">scaffold_3$"`. You should specify the end of line marker, which `$` represents - which is absolutely fine

Comment: But i am not sure that there will be no other character before the end of the line. Maybe I should use a ['space' if any]$ but [[:space:]] did not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know there's no whitespace after the text, then `grep ">scaffold_3$"` is right.

Or rather use single quotes since `$` is special within double quotes, and if you want to lock the beginning to start of line too, then add `^` or use `grep -x`. So `grep '^>scaffold_3$'` or `grep -x '>scaffold_3'`

(`-x` is `--line-regexp`: force PATTERN to match only whole lines)

If you can have whitespace at the end of the line and want to ignore any,
then

```
grep -e '>scaffold_3[[:space:]]*$'
```

would match any amount of optional whitespace between the string and the end of line. (And would also accept the match regardless of where in the line it starts.)

Note that if the file can have Windows-style CRLF line endings, then `>scaffold_3$` will *not* do, the CR at the end won't match the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

If i unstood it right you just want to have has a result the first entry of the file.

you can grep for the exact match of that string

```
grep -w ">scaffold_3" file.fasta
```

Comment: Both solutions worked (well, even `grep ">scaffold_3$"`) but the first (`grep -e`) seems more general. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, `grep -e` seemed more general but gave an error of pattern not recognized. `grep -w` still got too many lines.  `grep '.$'` gave the best output...